# How to use Edit Text value for delay parameter in Handler?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am writing a mobile application for parking in android studio. On one activity, I have an Edit Text field where the user enters the parking time, then pays for the selected parking space, immediately after that he goes to another activity where the button with this place lights up red and it is necessary that with a delay equal to the parking time that the user specified the button turned green again.But here delay is a constant value that we enter ourselves. I tried them:

```java
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        button1.setBackgroundColor(-16711936);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(Park.this, Slot1.class);
            startActivity(intent1);
            }
        });
    }
}, 30000);
```

Comment: You have provided very little information. As far as I understand you want to get the parking time from the user input via an edittext. Then you want to pass the parking time to another activity in order to dirve the state of a button, is that right?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can get the time using an EditText assuming that the time unit will be in minutes.

```java
class ParkingRequestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // Other codes...
    private EditText etParkTimeInput;
    // Maybe some more codes...

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Other codes...
        etParkTimeInput = findViewById(R.id.parkTimeInputEditText);
        etParkTimeInput.setOnEditorActionListener((editText, actionId, event) -> {
            if(actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                // User pressed done button
                final String parkingTimeInput = editText.getText().toString();
                try {
                    int parkingTime = Integer.parseInt(parkingTimeInput);
                    // From now on we have the time in minutes as an integer
                    int parkingTimeInMilliseconds = parkingTime * 60 * 1000;
                    // parkingTimeInMilliseconds can be used as delay value for handler
                } catch(NumberFormatException exception) {
                    exception.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(ParkingRequestActivity.this, "Please enter a valid time", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    // Rest of the activity's code...
}
```

Is this what you want to achieve? Where does the button1 come from?

Comment: No, i have EditText on one activity, and buttons (parking places) on another activity. I need to pass a value to edit text from one activity to another and use this value as a delay for a command block, I used Handler

Comment: You need to pass a value to edit text or from edit text to another activity? You better add your activities you mention about. We can't solve your issues by guessing your code logic friend. You need to help us to help you.

Comment: This is my first time on this form how can i attach some more of my code so you can help me?

Comment: I see my friend, you can start by reading [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) if you can read well in English. If you have trouble with adding code or code formatting have look at [Editing](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).